# Where SparkKubernetesSensor actually poking?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow

Hi I have a airflow on k8s and one of my dags has a task that is SparkKubernetesSensor. Airflow explain sensor modes in [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html#airflow.sensors.base.BaseSensorOperator). But now I have a question about poking. I want to know what happen when a sensor want to poking? Airflow create a pod? and what means that it don't free the resources? don't free driver pod or executor pod? or both? Or the airflow worker poking until the situation meet.

my airflow version is 2.4.3 and apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes version is 4.4.0.

I want to know actually what happen when a SparkKubernetesSensor poking.